# add navigationbar in ABUnknownPersonViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
ABUnknownPersonViewController *unknownPersonViewController = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];

unknownPersonViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 400);

//unknownPersonViewController.displayedPerson = (ABRecordRef)[self buildContactDetails];
unknownPersonViewController.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;

UIButton *cancelBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
cancelBtn.frame = CGRectMake(262, 6, 54,30);
[unknownPersonViewController.view addSubview:cancelBtn];

[self presentModalViewController:unknownPersonViewController animated:YES];

[unknownPersonViewController release];
```

i am using UIViewcontroller and in this code i want that a bar like navigation bar will show in upper
side of this controller so i want to put cancel button on that bar.any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is embed your `ABUnknownPersonViewController` in a UINavigationController

```
UINavigationController *newNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:unknownPersonViewController];

[self presentModalViewController:newNavigationController animated:YES];   
[view release];

[newNavigationController release];
```

That way you wouldn't even have to add the button yourself, the `ABUnknownPersonViewController` would take care of it for you.

For more info check [Address Book Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the online documentation says "Important Unknown-person view controllers must be used with a navigation controller in order to function properly." So, unlike a lot of the utility view controllers, I don't think you should be invoking

```
[self presentModalViewController:unknownPersonViewController animated:YES];
```

But rather

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

I think if you look at their samples, you'll see they push using the navigation controller.